# Excel formula to sum if other column met some condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, vba

I need a formula to sum if other column's all the unique values.
They must be counted only once.

```
 Title               count     
 Chasing The Breeze    1
A Captivating Stare    3
A Captivating Stare    3
A Captivating Stare    3
A Captivating Stare    3
A Captivating Stare    3
Angelic                1
```

sum must be equal to =1+3+1=5

[sum if other column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3jap.jpg)

[image]

Comment: How to determine uniqueness?  If a data with title "A Captivating Stare" and count=2 exists in addition to your sample data, what sum is expected,  1+3+1=5 or 1+3+1+2=7?

Comment: This condition  title "A Captivating Stare" and count=2 won't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B8/COUNTIFS(A2:A8, A2:A8, B2:B8, B2:B8))
```

[image: sum_unique]

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have numbers in A1 to A10 you could do something like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10;A1:A10&"");A1:A10)
```

Comment: sorry missed the part where you wanted uniqness on the title column also